# CiviMobile App error when editing phone

Tags: mobile, civimobile

CiviMobile app on Android errors when trying to add or edit a phone number.

clicking save returns error "Please enter phone number"

App occasionally crashes when trying to add a phone number.  Other fields edit and save as expected.

CiviCRM 5.14 on Drupal 7.67
extensions:
CiviMobileAPI (com.agiliway.civimobileapi) version 3.1
CiviMobile (com.webaccessglobal.module.civimobile) version 2.0

Android App

Anyone else having this issue?  Thanks

Comment: Do you have still a problem? Would be happy to help you. Please feel free to write me andriy.stabryn@agiliway.com

Comment: Latest release works well.  Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Mine is still in testing, but yes, also seeing API errors on mobile app start. CiviCRM 5.14.1, Drupal 7.67.
There has been a new 3.1.1 release of CiviMobileAPI since your post you may want to try? I'm still seeing an error on app start with it.

Not sure about your CiviMobile, the app on play is com.agiliway.civimobile? Otherwise I don't think this: https://civicrm.org/extensions/civimobile/version-20 is required, or at least, it's an old dev and not related to the current API?